# How to index related SQL tables in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

There are 2 related tables: `categories` and `products`. `products` table has field `categoryId`, which contains `id` of it's category. How to index `products` table to get `name` or anything else of it's category?

I have 2 indexers for each table and one index.

```
// categories indexer
    {
        "name": "categories",
        "dataSourceName": "categories",
        "targetIndexName": "products",
            "fieldMappings": [
            {
                "sourceFieldName": "id",
                "targetFieldName": "id"
            },
            {
                "sourceFieldName": "name",
                "targetFieldName": "name"
            }
    }

// products indexer
    {
        "name": "products",
        "dataSourceName": "products",
        "targetIndexName": "products",
            "fieldMappings": [
            {
                "sourceFieldName": "id",
                "targetFieldName": "id"
            },
            {
                "sourceFieldName": "name",
                "targetFieldName": "name"
            },
                {
                "sourceFieldName": "categoryId",
                "targetFieldName": "categoryId"
            }
    }

// index
{  
    "name": "products",  
    "fields": [  
      {  
        "name": "id",  
        "type": "Edm.String",  
        ...  
      },
      {  
        "name": "categoryId",  
        "type": "Edm.String",  
        ...
      },
      {  
        "name": "category_name",  
        "type": "Edm.String",  
         ...
      },
      {  
        "name": "name",  
        "type": "Edm.String",  
        ...
      }
...
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view that joins `categories` and `products` tables,  potentially denormalizing all caregoryIds into a collection field of a product document. (You can use the same approach for other category data). Set up an indexer for that view.

Another approach is to create two separate search indexes for products and categories, and perform the joins in the search client code.

Comment: Can you give an example of doing a join in the search client code? Or at least point to documentation describing it?

Comment: @justin.m.chase you should do join in database. So I created SQL view that joins table and created one index for this view.